# What microcontrollers are suitable for a keypad

Tags: microcontroller, keyboard

I'm a beginner in electrical engineering but I'm into mechanical keyboards and I want to build a keypad (1 row, 6 cols).
I recently wrote a macro for a keyboard (ATmega32U4 microcontroller) using the [QMK Firmware](https://github.com/qmk) and I'd like to restart from there.

What microcontroller should I use to build this keypad and what resources or open-source projects should I look at to get there?
I prefer the AVR family since I'm more familiar with but any advice is helpful at this point!

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to connect the keypad to? A USB port? Something else?

Comment: Any micro at all would do what you want providing it has 6 pins free for the 6 buttons.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if a AVR wasn't capable of handling 6 buttons...

Comment: if USB you can take a look at vusb HIDKB implementation.

Comment: I mean, if you are using QMK, you should use one of the controllers it supports. Its in the documentation: https://docs.qmk.fm/#/hardware_avr

Comment: Also, do you care about the package? Would you prefer DIP, or is SOIC OK? presumably BGA would not be a good idea.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams isn't the ATmega32U4 a little too much for 6 buttons. Is there something smaller? Thanks.

Comment: @isar Don't worry about "overkill" it'll be fine. The cost of the chip will be absolutely swamped by PCBs if you have them made. If you are just going to prototype them, "surfboards" are available for most Quad-Flat pincounts. The other thing too, when you are starting out, it is better to copy and understand a design. Once you understand it, you can change it.

Comment: If you think the ATmega32u4 is overkill, but you want to keep with AVRs and you want a USB port, then the smallest/cheapest option is probably an ATmega8U2. It's about half the price, and slightly smaller. It also has about 1/4 of the flash and RAM and half the eeprom and hardware timers, and no ADCs or I2C. But still enough for what you want I expect.

Comment: @JackB thank you. I think that is what I was looking for.

Comment: The '16U2 is usually pennies more, and gives you double the flash.

Comment: @isar Great, I'll post it as an answer then.

Comment: Note: They physical layout of the switches does not, in principle, dictate the electrical layout. You may have a single row of six buttons, but electrically, those could be wired as two rows of three. Not a big deal for such a small keypad, but could be worth remembering if you ever want to design a bigger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you comments, it sounds like you want:

- An 8-bit AVR, because that is what you are used to
- A USB device port, so you can communicate with the computer
- A cheap chip, not so much to save £1, but so it doesn't feel like overkill

You can find that by going to this page on the Microchip website (Microchip now own Atmel, and make the AVRs): https://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1005

Then, in the "CPU type" box pick 8-bit AVR. Scroll across to the USB section and pick number of USB modules 1, 2 and 3, and then order by pricing. The displayed prices are only if you order 5000, so they will be a bit more expensive one at a time.

The winner on the list is the  ATmega8U2. It's about half the price, and slightly smaller than the ATmega32U4. It also has about 1/4 of the flash and RAM and half the eeprom and hardware timers, and no ADCs or I2C. But still enough for what you want I expect. Second place is the ATmega16U2, which is only 16 cents more, but has quite a lot more flash. If you don't want to stick with AVRs, then the PICs are even cheaper, but probably won't work with the QMK library.

Most manufacturers who have large complicated ranges have a similar tool, and they are great for finding the right chip.